# How do I go back to ('Try Again? Y/N ')

Tags: python, if-statement

```
while True:
n1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
n2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
tot = n1 + n2
print('total is',tot)
n3 = input('Try Again? Y/N ')
if n3.upper() == 'Y':
    continue
elif n3.upper() == 'N':
    print('Exiting...')
    break
else:
    print('Not a valid answer')
```

Hi all. I have 2 questions:

1. How do I go back to ('Try Again? Y/N ') if the user did not press a valid answer?
2. It crashes when the user does not enter a number for n1 and n2. How to solve that please?

Comment: Unless you properly indent and format your code it's almost impossible to understand it.

Comment: You need to learn about loops.  Then it will be easy.

Comment: If you don't want an exception when the user inputs a non-number, wrap the conversion calls in `try/except` blocks to intercept the errors.